# What should I do with my vested stocks from employer

Tags: united-states, employee-stock-options

What should I do with my vested shares from current employer if I decide to leave my current organization.

Another set of shares are would normally vest during my FMLA/Maternity leave and I plan to take a break for my new born. Can they delay the vesting schedule of my shares in the same way they skip the bonus, because you need to be company rolls at that time?

Comment: Please clarify. Do these stocks trade on the stock market? In general, start-ups give you stock options which vest over time, but if you cannot trade them on the stock market, their value is quite different.

Comment: I am not aware of a law that proscribes what occurs with vesting during FMLA (the law is specific that health insurance must continue).  This is a question for your HR department.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to forfeit your partially vested shares if you quit? If not, then you can choose to keep the shares if you believe the value of the shares will increase, taking in consideration of possible dilution of future equity rounds. If you just want to cash out, you can a) sell it on the public exchange, assuming the company is publicly traded, or b) if the company is private, find private buyers and negotiate sale price based on your understanding of the company.

Good luck.